# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having some serious issues with my Spring 4 / Thymeleaf setup. This is the error message:

```
Error resolving template "public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

For some reason, Spring or Thymeleaf is treating css and js as if they are not static and trying to process them as if they were a request. I have 3 template resolvers:

```
    @Bean()
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(0);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean()
public TemplateResolver publicTemplateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/default/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean()
public TemplateResolver customPublicTemplateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/custom/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}
```

The pages are being served, the only issue is that the css and js is not. I am getting an error for each and every css and js that is included in the .html file. I literally moved a test css file to every possible directory trying to access it, but I am out of ideas at this point. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and if I need to further configure something.

**EDIT 03/31/2015**

src/main/webapp/templates/default/page99.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="resources/css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${content.title}"> PAGE 99 (/templates/default/page99.html)</h1>
<p th:text="${content.body}">This is dummy content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The css is a simple file that only sets the background color, just so I can see it working.

Comment: How are you including the bootstrap files in your project? Are you using webjar or are you manually including the js files in your project directory?

Comment: I'm not using the web jars, the files are in my project

Comment: Is this a `spring-boot` app or vanilla spring?

Comment: spring boot, I have it setup to generate a war file instead of a jar.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the JavaScript as a template, rather than linking to it as a static file. Can you update your question with one of your templates that isn't working?

Comment: I updated my answer and pasted the template. It's a really basic and simple template to try to get things to work. This site has an admin and public site. The admin was working fine up until recently, than all of a sudden, spring is trying to handle all of my links as if they were requests.

Comment: The really strange thing is that it is removing the extension for the css and js files. I'm not sure what happened to cause this, I can't get any css or js to load.

Comment: I just created a whole new project and carefully moved everything over, I am still facing the same issue. Thymeleaf is trying to resolve the css/js as if it was a request. Not sure where to find the setting or what I have to do in order to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

when you reference items on your server you should use the thymeleaf @ method for this in the corresponding thymeleaf attributes.

Like:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This generates correct URLs for you.
The css is in my case in src/main/resources/static/css/style.css